# Proving the uniformly asymptotically stability of a null solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, inequality, asymptotics, stability-in-odes

I would like to show that the null solution $ψ(t) ≡ 0$ of the equation $\frac{dx}{dt} = − \frac{x}{t}$, $(x,t)∈R×[a,+∞)$, $(a >0)$, is uniformly stable, asymptotically stable, but not uniformly asymptotically stable.

I've achieved to show the first two (uniformly stable and asymptotically stable), but I'm stuck on the last one. Indeed The definiton of uniformly asymptotically stability that I have is the following:

A solution $ψ(t)$ of $\frac{dx}{dt} = f(t,x)$ is uniformly asymptotically stable $\iff \exists ζ > 0$, $\forall η > 0$, $\exists T(η)$ such that $\forall t_0$, $||ξ - \psi(t_0)|| < ζ$, $t > t_0  + T \implies ||φ(t;t0,ξ) - \psi(t)|| < \eta$.

I've tried showing this property isn't true directly, however I always ended with an inequality where the right-hand side depended on $T(\eta)$, and since it should be true $\forall T(\eta)$, I couldn't conclude. Thus I tried showing it wasn't true by contradiction, i.e showing that:

$\forall ζ > 0$, $\exists η > 0$, $\forall T(η)$ such that $\exists t_0$, $||ξ - \psi(t_0)|| \geq ζ$, $t \leq t_0  + T$ and $||φ(t;t0,ξ) - \psi(t)|| \geq \eta$.

But again I didn't achieve the desired result.

Thus if anyone has an idea how to show this property, I'd love some help on that!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not exactly sure, but your question said you wanted to prove it WASN'T uniformly asymptotically stable,  therefore you aren't trying to show that property, you're trying to show the negation.

Comment: Yup sorry it was just a tipo, I tried showing IT WASN'T true by arriving at some contradiction.

Comment: So whatwould be negation here?

Comment: You'd flip all the quantifiers.  So show that for all,  there exists,  for all,   there exists a $t_0$  such that the final inequality doesn't hold.

Comment: Thank you @Alan, this looks a lot like the contradiction I stated, I am correct?

Comment: not sure, and alas, hungry and tired, heading out. Hopefully someone else can help!

Comment: Thank you for your help so far already :) I also hope someone else can help haha